# Excel dynamic ranges from Access code and Formula separators

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am currently rewriting some old Access code that defined named ranges in an excel workbook.
The old code is as follow:

```
oWorkbook.Names.Add "NameOfRange", "='Sheet1'!$A$1:$L2000"
```

With `oWorkbook` a Workbook opened from Access.

Since the range (number of rows) can change, I planned to use dynamic named ranges using Offset and CountA functions, and wrote the following code to replace the previous one:

```
oWorkbook.Names.Add "NameOfRange", "=OFFSET('Sheet1'!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA('Sheet1'!$A:$A),12)"
```

but then excel send an error 1004 `There is a problem with this formula`.

The same line of code executed from an Excel workbook works fine, and give the expected result.

On my computer, I use mixed English/French international settings, and my Office 2016 is in English, so I have a ListSeparator as `;`.

When replacing the `,` by `;`, the new formula below works:

```
oWorkbook.Names.Add "NameOfRange", "=OFFSET('Sheet1'!$A$1;0;0;COUNTA('Sheet1'!$A:$A);12)"
```

but I need my function to work on every configuration, not on only French/English bizaroid settings.

I tried to specify the named arguments (`Name:= ...` and `RefersTo:=...`) but its not correcting the problem. When called from Access, the code still need local separators (and maybe local function names? no idea).

So I can retrieve the computer excel List Separator (Using `oWorkbook.Application.International(xlListSeparator)` and replace all `,` in the formula with it, but maybe I am doing something wrongly and there is a better way to do?

Comment: You said the formula works on excel. It works when you type or it works when you try to use vba to populate a cell? Because excel has some weird interactions when you try to insert a formula on a cell via vba.

Comment: The code is not used to populate cells, it is used to create a dynamic named range (see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830287/how-to-create-a-dynamic-defined-range-in-an-excel-worksheet) )